# Can voltage ripple be lowered even more after the regulator?

Tags: power

Just wondering if the voltage ripple can be lowered even more after leaving the voltage regulator. Going in is 7.2 V after using two 4700 µF, a 1 µF, and then a 0.1 µF capacitor. The regulator will then output 5 V, 5 A. Can the ripple be reduced even more using the same combination but in reverse after the regulator? Starting with 0.1 and ending with two 4700 µF before the bleed resistor. This is my first project, still learning the maths.
just to add The regulator is this MIC29500-5.0WT MICROCHIP Fixed LDO Voltage Regulator, 2.5V to 26V, 370mV Dropout, 5V/5A out

Comment: That's a lot more capacitance than is probably necessary. || Every regulator I've ever used *requires* capacitance on its output. || If you want to lower noise even further, you can always add a suitable LC filter.

Comment: Filters, but regulation and transient response will suffer. Also if you don't do it right, it can make it worse if your filter has a peak that lands on one of the frequencies. What type of regulator is this and where are you feeding it from?

Comment: That is quite a lot of capacitance on your line and sound be sufficient for most applications. Use a combination of electrolytic caps for high capacitance values >47uF and ceramic caps for low capacitance values <10uF. This should help in reducing voltage ripple with varying current demands.

Comment: cheers lads. the 1uf and 0.1uf are ceramic caps.

Comment: I've added the regulator to the main post. it's a 6v toroidal in parallel to output 8amps into a bridge rectifier and then into the caps. the voltage drop across the rectifier is stated at 1.1v

Comment: With this regulator having a 0.01 ohm output resistance, trying to smooth ripple with an output capacitor is pretty much pointless. However, output resistance starts to rise above a few kilohertz, so adding a smoothing output capacitor is possible, but still difficult.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the ripple be reduced even more using the same combination but in reverse after the regulator?

Totally depends on the regulator. If you have higher ripple than expected then it could be:-

- an indication of a design issue which requires a design review (and revision, if necessary)
- or a measurement issue which is quite a common thing. To see how to measure the output ripple accurately, have a look at [this article](https://www.cui.com/blog/how-to-measure-ripple-and-transient-in-power-supplies).

If it's a linear regulator, not all regulators are happy with higher capacitance across their outputs. Instead of increasing the output capacitance randomly, consider an external LC filter block (see below).

If it's a switching regulator,

- You can start with trying lower-ESR capacitors. Some designs may require non-zero ESR, though.
- You can play with the compensation network if the design has one already, or at least allows you to use an external network. It has a direct effect on the dynamic behaviour as well as the output ripple.
- You can't randomly increase the output capacitance as it may lead to startup and stability or dynamic behaviour problems since the choke and the output capacitance appear in the transfer function. It's better to add LC block(s) "after" the output voltage sampling point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0bnBr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adding an extra RC or LC network usually works on **linear regulators** as well, especially on LDOs which usually don't like high output capacitance.

Comment: The regulator is this MIC29500-5.0WT
MICROCHIP Fixed LDO Voltage Regulator,
2.5V to 26V, 370mV Dropout, 5V/5A out

Comment: @PhilHebden please add this info to your question body.